# Guidance on Angular (Dart) web app route design possibly using Information Architecture (IA) or not

Tags: angularjs, routes, dart, angular-dart

Is anyone aware of documentation describing **route design** for an Angular app? In particular any relationship / possible benefits of using a **Information Architecture** (**IA**) artifacts like site maps.

---

What is IA? See the [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com) "[About `information-architecture`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/information-architecture/info)" tag description. At a minimum, one might consider a "site map" as a key IA artifact: [see below](http://bitstrategist.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2010/09/site_map_sample.pdf) for an example (taken from a blog entry on IA). Of course there is more to IA than that.

[image: http://bitstrategist.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2010/09/site_map_sample.pdf]

Comment: What do you mean by "Information Architecture (IA)"?

Comment: I missed a lot of your questions because I monitor only the [dart] tag. I would add the dart tag to all Dart related questions. I have the impression that many do the same as questions without the generic dart tag get seldom answers.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: ok, I add the dart tag too.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be everything you're after, but there are some docs from Google that might be of use:

- [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub)
- [An AngularJS Style Guide for Closure Users at Google](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html)